# break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch

Tags: java

```
String value = custom.getdob().toString();
if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
    holder.item3.setText("-");
    break;
}
```

I am actually over-riding the method getView, so i am not able to place a `return` after my if condition as it says view must be returned, but i want to exit the if condition after the check. so tried out `break` and i am getting this error "**break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch**"

```
    break; = > Throws break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch
    return; = > This method must return a result of type View
```

Comment: Please paste your entire method, or at least all relevant parts. Also explain what you want to achieve with break, and what are you actually asking...

Comment: If you have code you don't want to execute, use an if statement.  If you want to exit the method, use a return statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you even need a `break` there? The `if` block has finished anyway, so control will exit the block.

If you wanna return the view instead of `break;`, put `return holder;` (assuming holder is a view)

break can only be used in switch & loops (for/while/do-while)

Answer (score 3):

I think that in this particular case you can return null to exit from method.

Answer (score 1):

`return viewObject;` you must use. Seems to be method signature is

> public View getView(){...}

And it clearly says it should return View object or null. So you can use `return null;` or return the expected view object.